# Turn in which direction to loosen the bolts for engine torque mount?

Tags: lexus, motor-mounts, bolts, es-300

For a 1997 Lexus ES300, what is the direction to turn the wrench when I want to loosen the bolts for removing the motor mount? The one I'm trying to replace is the one on top that is very accessible and secured by 2 bolts, one to engine and another to frame (torque mount).

*My research on other model years:*

From a [forum thread](http://www.fixya.com/cars/t10849812-thread_direction_camshaft_sprocket_bolt) for the **1998** model, one answer claims its '**lefty loosey**', aka counter-clockwise? Similarly [the tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mtFfXgYyOo) of a motor mount replacement for a **2003** model also shows both bolts being turned **counter-clockwise**.

One of the forum comments also said it should be 'threaded against the direction of rotation', if so perhaps I can infer that '97 is also counter-clockwise rotation to loosen.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good assumption to think ***all bolts are lefty-loosey*** or counter-clockwise to loosen them (considered right hand threads). Left hand threaded fasteners used to be a lot more prevalent, but hardly used for automotive purposes anymore. There are exceptions, but generally they are very hard to find.

Comment: I thought a left-hand thread is a rare thing, like those in bicycle pedals, or holding the chuck in place on a reversible electric hand drill. Right-hand threaded fasteners are in the majority, yes?

Comment: @fred_dot_u - You may be right in that I mixed up terms ... because right hand threads are the direction you tighten them, not loosen them ... I'll correct my answer and thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I have removed several motor mounts and never found a left hand thread .